# Making wall see through only on one side

Tags: materials, transparency

I am creating a space in Blender that is essentially a deli on the outside and I want it to be a gallery on the inside (for Mozilla hubs) and I would like the window to be able to see through from the outside but when you're inside there is no window. In order to achieve this, I need the wall in-between to be transparent on one side and solid on another. I hope this makes sense.

Sometimes this happens accidentally on my other projects but would love to know if there's a way to achieve this fully.

Comment: I also enabled backface culling and that worked too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mix your see-through window material (exemplified in my image by a *Transparent BSDF*) with your non-see through material (*Principled BSDF*) using the *Backfacing* Output of A *Geometry (shader) Node* as the *Mix Factor*:

[image: Backfacing]

NOTE - Make sure to switch the materials *Blend Mode* to something other than *Opaque* if you are using EEVEE.